# ArrayList is showing only last element

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have list of Integers that I want to show inside TextView (using RecyclerView).Problem is that each time my integer is overridden by last element.I'm calling this method inside bind method of ViewHolder.
Is it possible to use setText instead of append and have each integer written to textview?

```
    public void showRankings(){
        Integer[] rankingsArray = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20};
        List<Integer> rankings = Arrays.asList(rankingsArray);


        for (Integer i : rankings){
          rankingsTxt.setText("#" + Integer.toString(i));
        }
   }
```

Full  ViewHolder :

```
public class TvHolder extends ButterKnifeVH  {
  @Bind(R.id.trade_btn) AutoResizeTextView tradeBtn;
  @Bind(R.id.gain_lose) public AutoResizeTextView gainTxt;
  @Bind(R.id.symbolName) public AutoResizeTextView symbolName;
  @Bind(R.id.parent) ConstraintLayout constraintLayout;
  @Bind(R.id.ranking) AutoResizeTextView rankingsTxt;

  @BindString(R.string.percent_string) String strPercent;

  private FragmentActivity fragmentActivity;
  private TopsFlopsView topsFlopsView;
  private TopsFlopsSymbolEntity topsEntity;


  public TvHolder(ViewGroup parent, int layoutId
      ,FragmentActivity fragmentActivity,TopsFlopsView topsFlopsView) {
    super(parent, layoutId);
    this.topsFlopsView = topsFlopsView;
    this.fragmentActivity = fragmentActivity;
  }
  public void bind(TopsFlopsSymbolEntity topsEntity){
    symbolName.setText(topsEntity.getSymbol());
    showRankings();
  }


        public void showRankings(){
            Integer[] rankingsArray = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20};
            List<Integer> rankings = Arrays.asList(rankingsArray);


            for (Integer i : rankings){
              rankingsTxt.setText("#" + Integer.toString(i));
            }
       }

  }


}
```

Here is main part of Adapter which is working fine

```
public class TopsAdapter
    extends RealmRecyclerViewAdapter<TopsFlopsSymbolEntity, RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

  private FragmentActivity context;
  private TopsFlopsView view;

  public TopsAdapter(Realm realm) {
    super(realm);
  }

  @Override
  public void onBindRealmViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, TopsFlopsSymbolEntity tops) {
    if(holder instanceof TopsViewHolder){{
      ((TopsViewHolder) holder).bind(tops);
    }}
  }

  @Override public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new TopsViewHolder(parent, R.layout.tops_flops_item, context, view);
  }
```

Comment: Provide us the complete code like how you wrote your adapter

Comment: This code will always set `rankingsTxt`'s  `text`  field  to the last value of  rankings. provide your whole code

Comment: try `rankingsTxt.setText(rankingsTxt.getText() + "#" + Integer.toString(i));`

Comment: Better yet, use a [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) to build the text, iteratively with [StringBuilder.append(String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append-java.lang.String-) -- *then* set rankingsTxt to its value.

Comment: @praveendewangan I'm calling this method inside viewholder, adapter is working fine.

Comment: Just want to understand what exactly you're trying to achieve, do you want to have a list of ```TextView``` items each being set to a rank number based on, let's say for example, position within the list?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following snippet -

```
...
...
String textToDisplay = "";
for (Integer i : rankings){
   textToDisplay = textToDisplay + " #" + Integer.toString(i);
}

rankingsTxt.setText(textToDisplay);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to create one String which you want to display into view or get previous from `rankingsTxt` and append new value with previous value like `rankingsTxt.getTest()+ new value`  and again set it.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you.

```
public void showRankings() {
    Integer[] rankingsArray = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20};
    List<Integer> rankings = Arrays.asList(rankingsArray);

    String str = "";
    for (Integer i : rankings) {
        str = str + "#" + Integer.toString(i);
    }
    rankingsTxt.setText(str);
}
```

Comment: Edit your question with the java and xml codes for activity and recycler view

Comment: @Xample did You try adding "\n" after each number ?